# perl: run another script without exec/system

Tags: perl

Is it possible to include/source another perl script, or launch it as a "sub"?
This works, but looks ugly:

test2.pl:

```
print "I'm in test2.pl; args: @ARGV\n";
```

test.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use File::Temp qw/tempdir/;
use File::Copy qw/copy/;

my $tmplib;

use lib ($tmplib = tempdir()) . (
  copy("./test2.pl", "$tmplib/test2.pm") ? "" : (die "$!")
  );

use test2;
```

x

```
$ ./test.pl a b c
I'm in test2.pl; args: a b c
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that, is the question that matters. This is a bad solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you want the [`do` operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html), although it also sounds like very bad design.

This is what the documentation says.

> ```
> do EXPR Uses the value of EXPR as a filename and executes the contents
>         of the file as a Perl script.
> ```

```
            do 'stat.pl';

        is just like

            eval `cat stat.pl`;
```

Comment: I need to debug a script under Eclipse and I want to make some preparations before the actual script is launched.

Comment: Breakpoints are not updated when a new module is loaded with 'do'.

Comment: If you are getting the right effect with `use` and not with `do` then it is probably because `use` is executed at compile time. Just write `BEGIN { do 'test2.pl' }` instead and it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `do` to run another Perl script in the same interpreter:

```
do 'test2.pl';
```

This will reuse the command line parameters from the outer script.  To pass different parameters, you can override `@ARGV` locally, like:

```
{
    local @ARGV = qw(par1 par2 par3);
    do 'test2.pl';
}
```